# Hide Status bar in android

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native 0.55.3
How can do like in a image

Android screen shot

[image]

to

Ios screen shot

[image]

Comment: Is there something you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [StatusBar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#docsNav) component api of react-native for this purpose, that will help to hide status bar and you can change color of status bar depending on the scene on you are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to understand your point. But answering on the possibility you trying to achieve.
Here `Color` as per platform.

```
<StatusBar
     backgroundColor= {Platform.os =="ios"? "IOS_COLOR_CODE" : "ANDROID_COLOR_CODE"}
     barStyle="light-content"
   />
```

Hiding status bar

```
<StatusBar
    hidden ={true}
    barStyle="light-content"
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <StatusBar backgroundColor={'transparent'} translucent={true} />
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make your colorPrimaryDark same as that of colorAccent in colors.xml.
I think you have added some extra view above the actionbar

Answer (score 0):

**you can hide Status bar like this:**

```
 <StatusBar
    hidden={true}
 />
```

or

`StatusBar.setHidden(true);`

---

**and change the color:**

```
<StatusBar
  backgroundColor="pink"
  barStyle="light-content"
/>
```

or

`StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('pink');`

---

**if you use `'react-native-navigation'`:**

```
 appStyle: {
    statusBarColor: 'pink',
    statusBarTextColorScheme: 'light-content',
    statusBarHidden: true,
 }
```